# Ubuntu 20.04 constantly runs out of disk space

Tags: 20.04, ssd, disk-usage

I have recently moved over again, from Win 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Precision, mainly for software development.

My total disk SSD memory is 256GB. Bad choice and being a work laptop I am stuck with it.

My issue is that daily I run out of storage space. Sometimes it is because of ACPI errors filling up the var/log files

Edit: i added some of the more frequent error messages:

```
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617345] 
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617346] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L69]
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617347] 
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617348] No Arguments are initialized for method [_L69]
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617348] 
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617349] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L69 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210604/psparse-529)
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.617353] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L69] (20210604/evgpe-511)
Nov 20 00:00:05 andreitulbure-Precision-7760 kernel: [97720.618503] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L69.D6F0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210604/psargs-330)
```

Sometimes I have no idea. The /var folder is small and the file manager only shows me 150GB instead of 256GB of storage and then everything freezes on my PC.

I am really frustrated because I am kinda familiar with Ubuntu, having used it a lot in the past and this never happened to me. Also I had a horrific experience on Win so I want to make Ubuntu work for me.

Any suggestions would be helpful. I really tried googling from where the ACPI errors come from and Try to solve them, but I Have been unsuccesful.

Thanks!

Best regards,

Comment: What is the hardware of your system?  There is a possibility that you are filling up with ACPI errors with an incorrect video card driver installed or missing video card driver.  Looking at my logs on my system that I had just reinstalled about 4 nights ago, I see my ACPI errors go away once I had installed the drivers back into my system.  Plus, the errors no longer appeared at startup.

Comment: Well, I am using original nvidia drivers. My HW is a dell precision with Nvidia T1200 GPU. Yes, I get tons of ACPI errors. The reason I am using this nvidia-driver is because this is apprently the only way I could to use 3 monitors.
I am using nvidia-driver-470.141.10, cuda 11.4

Comment: You should be able to use the nvidia-driver-520 from the Ubuntu repos or the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`  Either way, they should install extra files as well for ACPI interface and others.

Comment: Not a solution but a workaround. You can set to automatically remove the log files with `sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=20M`. It will cap them to 20MB, and delete older logs.

Comment: My problem is regarding kern.log, syslog.log mostly. I capped journal. I am using now 520 driver and I still get ACPI errors. A ton of.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the ACPI errors you are seeing?  No need for them all, just a copy and paste from the file a few lines will do.

Comment: @Terrance edited. Thanks!

Comment: Check and see if you have the `linux-firmware` package installed.  `apt-cache policy linux-firmware`

Comment: @Terrance Yes, I have 
`(base) andreitulbure@andreitulbure-Precision-7760:~$ sudo apt-cache policy linux-firmware
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 1.187.34
  Candidate: 1.187.34
  Version table:
 *** 1.187.34 500
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.187 500
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages`

Comment: I am really running out of ideas, but the last thing I can think of is possibly needing a BIOS update.  https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=y2v4k&oscode=wt64a&productcode=precision-17-7760-laptop

Comment: @Terrance I do not have a bios update pending and I am scared to not mess up the storage (burned myself with Windows once). Moreover, when I restart the laptop, it clears out 100GB of memory just by restarting (wtf)